# How to put list of id's as a list without them being changed into integers

Tags: r

I have a list of dispatch codes I am working with and am trying to plot a barchart.

The issue is that they have values like `29D00V` and when I check their type using type of they come out as integer.

I want to plot them as categoricals on the x axis of my barchart but when I convert them into a list using `c(rows_to_use$Group.1)` it turns them into integers.

e.g. `24D01` becomes `568`
I suspect it is reading them as Hex values and then converting them into integers. Is there an easy way of changing the entire Group.1 column of the dataframe into type string?

Here is the current iteration of my script:

```
#read csv
df <-        read.csv(file="C:/Users/GIGNWI_Ar208671/Documents/R/Projects/CallTimes/call_times/data/risks_codes_descriptions.csv",header=TRUE)
#correct garbled column name
colnames(df)[1] = "call_times"
rows_to_use <-df
#initialise new name, this is where filter will be applied if applicable
rows_to_use = aggregate(x = rows_to_use$call_times,by=    (list(rows_to_use$DispatchCodeAndSuffix)),median)
#Take the median of each dispatch code in the list
rows_to_use <- rows_to_use[order(-rows_to_use$x),]
#Order by largest to smallest median call time
rows_to_use <-head(rows_to_use,100)
#Take the top 100
x = c(rows_to_use$x)
y = c(rows_to_use$Group.1)
#Create vectors for bar plot
barchart(x, names.arg=y)
#Plot barchart
print(2)
```

Comment: Instead of editing your question to include the answer in the body, you should post it below as an answer. In 24 hours (for a self-answered question) you can "accept" the answer which will mark the question as complete.

Comment: Thanks Gregor, I've changed it now. Pretty new so still getting to grips with the rules

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I solved it if anyone else has this problem just specify the datatype of the column in the read.csv using colClasses e.g.

```
 df <-read.csv(file="C:/Users/GIGNWI_Ar208671/Documents/R/Projects/CallTimes/call_times/data/risks_codes_descriptions.csv",header=TRUE,colClasses=c("DispatchCodeAndSuffix"="character"))
```